# Topology question: Connected and bounded 2D spaces are compact surfaces in 3D

Tags: general-topology

Just a question arised in my mind. This is the first time i am studying this subject. If there is a counter example, what it is? If this is true then how shall i work towards proving it?

Comment: What makes you think this could be true? Is $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ a compact surface in 3D?

Comment: It is not!  Thanks